# Read user input matrix to twodimensional array

Tags: javascript

I create a form with matrix like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for(var j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                {
                    var input = $('<input>')
                        .attr({
                            class: 'matrix_cell',
                            value: 0});
                    form.appendChild(input[0]);
                }
                var br = $('<br>')[0];
                form.appendChild(br);
            }
```

And I want to read a matrix that user inputted to two-dimensional array and then pass it to php file  in ajax query.

I tried this way:

```
function getMatrix(){
        var matrix_row = []

        $("#matrix_form").find("input").each(function(i){
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (!isNaN(value)){
                matrix_row[i] = value;
            }
        });

        return matrix_row;
    }
```

But it reads matrix to onedimensional array.

Comment: It looks like you're only inputting into a one dimensional array.  You need another counter so you can do something along the lines of matrix_row[i][j] = value;

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/hcbLozd7/

```
function getMatrix(){
    var matrix_row = [];

    var ind = 0;

    $("#frm").contents().each(function(i,e){ //for all contents in div
        if (this.nodeName == "INPUT") //if it's input
        {
            if (!matrix_row[ind]){  //it matrix doesn't have a new array, push a new array
                matrix_row.push([]);
            }
             matrix_row[ind].push($(this).val()); //add input value to array inside array
        }
        else{ //when element is br
            ind++;  //increment counter
        }
    });

    return matrix_row;
}
```